# Swift get all items in enum

Tags: swift, dictionary, iterator

I have properties in enum and I need an array of those constants to match them with String key.
I need to iterate through them automatically. I cannot change input since it is generated.

```
public enum Items {
    public static let a = Assets(named: "A")
    public static let b = Assets(named: "B")
    public static let c = Assets(named: "C")
    public static let d = Assets(named: "D")
    public static let e = Assets(named: "E")
}
```

I tried Mirror them.

Comment: Please add your attempt and the expected result.

Comment: `Items` and `Assets` should be named `Item` and `Asset`. The single object is not plural.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just using the enum as a placeholder to put your static variables in, it's easy. Just create a static array with all the properties in it.

```
struct Assets
{
    let name: String
    var assets: String { "assets for \(name)" }

    init(named: String)
    {
        self.name = named
    }
}

enum Items2 {
    static let a = Assets(named: "A")
    static let b = Assets(named: "B")
    static let c = Assets(named: "C")
    static let d = Assets(named: "D")
    static let e = Assets(named: "E")

    static var allItems: [Assets] { return [a, b, c, d, e] }
}


for item in Items2.allItems
{
    print(item.assets)
}
```

However, if you are concerned that you might forget to add new properties to the array, you can use the enum properly. Use an enum with a `rawValue` of `String` and that conforms to `CaseIterable` and define all your cases. Then add a property that gets the `Assets` based on the case's rawValue. Then you can use the enum's `allCases` property to get all the cases.

```
enum Items: String, CaseIterable
{
    case a = "A"
    case b = "B"
    case c = "C"
    case d = "D"
    case e = "E"

    var assets: Assets { Assets(named: rawValue) }

    static var allItems: [Assets] { allCases.map{ $0.assets } }

}

for item in Items.allItems
{
    print(item.assets)
}
```

A `CaseIterable` enum has the `allCases` property synthesised automatically. If you add a new case it is automatically in `allCases`.

Comment: I am using Swiftgen generated strong typed assets. It uses enum as a container and I was thinking about using something like Mirror, that works for struct and class. It is 100+ items, but I am also pretty sure that it cannot be converted without putting them all inside all values array.

Comment: @michals92 You should add that comment to the question. It's information that is important to people wanting to write answers.